# how to count items inside group_concat method with mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have one to many table relationship :

- one `user` for multiple `event`
- one `event` for multiple `event_attribute`

Now, I group by `userId` and want to know **how many for each event attribute ?**

I am using `group_concat` like this:

```
group_concat(  
concat(event_event_attribute.event_attr_id, 
       count( distinct event_event_attribute.value) 
      ) group by event_attr_id)
)
group by userId
```

So here, I first group by `userId`, then group concat `event-attribute`, at least I hope to have :

```
(attr1, 10),(attr2, 30)....
```

all in one row.

But this does not work at all

Any suggestions?

To be more specific, this is the DB schema I am using:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `event_attr` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `att_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `event_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `user` VALUES (1,'user1'),(2,'user2'),(3,'user3');
INSERT INTO `event` VALUES (1,'event1',1),(2,'event2',1),(3,'event3',1),(4,'event4',2),(5,'event5',2),(6,'event6',3);
INSERT INTO `event_attr` VALUES (1,'att1','1'),(2,'att2','1'),(3,'att3','1'),(4,'att1','2'),(5,'att2',NULL);
```

Now if I am running:

```
select u.id, group_concat(e.name)
from user u 
join event e on u.id=e.user_id 
group by u.id
```

I will get:

```
1 event1,event2,event3
2 event4,event6
3 event 6
```

That is fine. But one step forward, I need to know count for each event_attt for each user, such as:

```
1 evet_att1:3;event_att2:2
2 event_att3:1
```

Then it is not possible. Can I use just one query to get above expected response?

Comment: the thing you posted is not a query.  post your query, post the results you get, post the results you want.  bonus: post your table schema.  double bonus: post sample data.  **triple bonues!**: post a sql fiddle!

Answer (score 0):

should be the inverse alias concat the aggreagted  values and not aggregated  the concat

```
 select concat (group_concat(event_event_attribute.event_attr_id )
          ,' - ',  
         count( distinct event_event_attribute.value) )
 from event_event_attribute
 group by userid
```

Otherwise could be you need  an subquery for obtain the count group by event_attr_id

```
select group_concat(
    concat(event_attr_id), ',', count_value)
)
from t (
    select user_id, event_event_attribute.event_attr_id, count( distinct event_event_attribute.value)  count_value
    from event_event_attribute
    group by event_attr_id
) t 
group by user_id
```

Comment: Hello, the problem in your solution is you are not grouping by event_attr_id, one user has many events, we need to could each event attribute's count instead of all the attribute as a whole

Comment: your expected  result is not coherent with e data in your sample  eg: att1 is related  only tu user 1 and 2 so hwo you expected thre result evet_att1:3; ????

Comment: Hi ScaisEdge, response is only for demo purpose, but the goal is to return each event attribute count in one row, so that we can display the result in one table row. I could not figure out how to do count inside group_concat, the only way I can think is to get all the userId and then use subQuery to count each event attribute. Then combine results.
But this solution is making sorting impossible. Do you have any idea?